# Are there different greases for inner and outer CV joints?

Tags: axle, grease, cv-joint

I was watching a video by Eric the Car Guy on changing a CV boot.  In it he mentioned that there are two different types of grease, for inner and outer CV joints, which can be identified by the colour of the grease.

According to him "[inner joint grease is yellow](https://youtu.be/-S-ofMoWsr0?t=15m36s)" and [the outer grease is green](https://youtu.be/-S-ofMoWsr0?t=5m43s).

Is this true for all axles or just for some?

**EDIT**

They don't sell boot kits in my country. So I have to buy the grease separately and I want to make sure I get the right one. If it matters it's for a 99 Nissan Almera which is similar to the Sentra sold in the states

**EDIT 12/1/16**

A [search of amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_12?url=search-alias%3Dautomotive&field-keywords=cv%20joint%20grease&sprefix=CV%20joint%20gre%2Caps%2C403) doesn't turn up anything other that CV and CV-2 grease and then there is one labelled "w/Moly".  But nothing labelled inner or outer grease.

Comment: Definitely not true for all drive shafts.  Most of the ones I have replaced have had both CV joints like the outer ones in his video.  Molybdenum grease is the norm for those.  It looked like it was Lithium grease in his inner CV joint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

True for some axles. Given the different bearing designs between the inner and out CV joint. The CV joints will include the required grease when purchased. The color depends more on the manufacturer than anything. There are aftermarket (read: Valvoline, Castrol, etc) greases that can be used in the inner and outer cv joint.

Comment: They don't sell boot kits in my country.  So I have to buy the grease separately and I want to make sure I get the right one.  If it matters it's for a 99 Nissan Almera which is similar to the Sentra sold in the states.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Any CV grease that contains molybdenum disulfide or Moly grease is fine. Do not use wheel bearing grease, its different.

Comment: This is what they had at my local parts shop:  VALVOLINE MULTIPURPOSE GREASES s a superior general purpose NLGI #2
grade lithium complex grease with molybdenum disulfide. It is designed to provide excellent extreme pressure and antiwear protection for wheel bearings, chassis, suspension systems, steering linkage
and universal joints ( so I guess it's OK? ) http://content.valvoline.com/pdf/multipurpose_grease.pdf

Comment: Yes, that grease is OK.

Comment: But you should clean the old grease out before adding new cv axle grease!